# How to expose only the required data to an API route?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have a model:

```py
class User(Base):
  id = Column()
  username = Column()
  password = Column()
  field1 = Column()
  field2 = Column()
  field3 = Column()
```

Now, in a particular route `api/v1/fetch_only_essentials` I don't need that route to see/access whole of my user data but instead only access fields field1, 2 and 3.

I heard something like response_model but I'm not finding any relevant implementation. Any help from the community?

Comment: This is documented in the reference guide here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#add-an-output-model - I've linked directly to the section showing how to use an specific output model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create pydantic model for your User class in your case this should do the trick

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
class UserSchema(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str
    password: str
```

Comment: You'll also have to tell your endpoint to use this schema with `@app.get('/foo', response_model=UserSchema)` - this will only include the fields you've defined in UserSchema.